# How do I create a blacklist/whitelist for finding Rails model records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, filter, find

I want to create a model, "Whitelist" to build a list of users that I do not want displayed in my main model, "User".

Example Controller

```
def index
    @users = User.find(:all) #These are to be filtered behind the scenes in the model
end
```

Example Model

```
class User ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :whitelist
def self.find
    #Add something that will lookup items in the Whitelist model and filter those matches out of a find(:all) in the User model.
end
```

I hope this makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: imho, you don't need a new model for this. just a new method that has the where method(if you're using rails 3)

Comment: Sadly Im using repo rails from Ubuntu which looks like 2.2.3

Comment: Looks like the where method will work with scope method that I found (Link to api is in my comment in the answer). I just have to upgrade rails somehow without breaking anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [named_scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/named_scope)

So in your user model:

```
named_scope :whitelist, :conditions => { :awesome => true }
```

And then in your controller:

```
User.whitelist
```

Comment: Your answer has lead me to http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope which, seems to have a join and a where condition that would work. I think I need to upgrade my rails install to use it but, this looks like it will work. Thanks for the help.